# Dollar sign on y-axis with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The labels on the Y-axis of my Chart.js chart should have a dollar sign in front because they are values of money.

This code is in the docs but doesn't work for me.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Here's my result. 'Before' is without this code, 'after' is with.
[image]
Apparently it is not just adding a `$` before the value, but something else is happening too.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just round the value!

Comment: Agree, but sometimes it should round on the 4th decimal and sometimes on the thousands.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that chart.js won't round a string, as it is not supposed to do that for you.

When you append a string to a number, JavaScript will convert it for you and you have no control over the precision.

You can use [toFixed](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) to solve your problem:

```
// Define wherever decimals:
const decimals = 3;
// ...
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value.toFixed(decimals);
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but the variable decimals changes every time the chart is loaded. It's dynamic data.

Comment: @yoeriboven just change `decimals` every time you need to change the amount of decimals to be shown...

Comment: @yoeriboven Don't know if you did the downvote, but what kind of answer did you expect? `Chart.js` won't round magically a number which is inside a string for you...

Comment: have anyway to do this without callback function? if answer is NO please tell why?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for Chart JS 3+ has changed from the current accepted answer. The new format is as follows -

```
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                    return '$' + value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Numeral JavaScript library (npm install numeral):

```js
import * as numeral from 'numeral'; //npm i numeral


ticks: {
    callback: (value: any) => {
      return numeral(value).format('$0,0.[00]')
    }
}
```

That should do the trick!